# Позиционирование для четных и нечетных элементов

Tags: html, css

Товарищи помогите!

Есть элементы "числа" нужно их спозиционировать абсолютно так что бы все нечетные элементы были за левым краем, а все четные за правым краем.

Заранее спасибо!

```css
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container{
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-advantages {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.main-advantages__goods {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-advantages__img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -18%);
    max-height: 984px;
    object-position: center center;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.main-advantages__inner {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 520px;
    &:nth-child(odd){
        text-align: right;
        padding: 130px 165px 0px 0;
    }
    &:nth-child(even){
        text-align: left;
        padding: 130px 0 0px 165px;
    }
}

.main-advantages__number {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 95px;
    height: 95px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    line-height: 1;
    span{
        transform: translate(0, -5px);
    }
}


.main-advantages__title {
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    font-size: 25px;

}
.main-advantages__text {
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="container">
  <section class="main-advantages">
    <div class="main-advantages__goods"> 
      <img class="main-advantages__img" src="img/rose.png" alt="Rose">
    </div>
    <div class="main-advantages__inner">
      <div class="main-advantages__number">
        <span>01</span>
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-advantages__title"> Эксклюзивная подача </h2>
      <p class="main-advantages__text"> Роскошный подарок в дизайнерской коробке, подписанная именем получателя – подарок, достойный королевы.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-advantages__inner">
      <div class="main-advantages__number">
        <span>02</span>
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-advantages__title"> Неповторимые эмоции </h2>
      <p class="main-advantages__text"> Неожиданно удивите и обрадуйте дорого вам человека, подарив ему внимание и коробку прекрасных, свежих роз.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-advantages__inner">
      <div class="main-advantages__number">
        <span>03</span>
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-advantages__title"> Осязаемая роскошь </h2>
      <p class="main-advantages__text"> Мы находимся вне конкуренции обычных букетов. Наша подача всегда будет выделяться на фоне остальных подарков.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-advantages__inner">
      <div class="main-advantages__number">
        <span>04</span>
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-advantages__title"> Длительная неувядаемость </h2>
      <p class="main-advantages__text"> Наши розы живы дольше, чем в шляпных коробках, поскольку каждый цветок мы укладываем в отдельную капсулу с водой</p>
    </div>
  </section>
      </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Код в студию (а не по ссылке)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Еще вариант без скрипта, с помощью :nth-child(odd)

```css
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container{
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-advantages {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.main-advantages__goods {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-advantages__img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -18%);
    max-height: 984px;
    object-position: center center;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.main-advantages__inner {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 520px;
    &:nth-child(odd){
        text-align: right;
        padding: 130px 165px 0px 0;
    }
    &:nth-child(even){
        text-align: left;
        padding: 130px 0 0px 165px;
    }
}

.main-advantages__number {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 95px;
    height: 95px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    line-height: 1;
    left:0;
    span{
        transform: translate(0, -5px);
    }
}

.main-advantages__inner:nth-child(odd) .main-advantages__number{
  left:auto;
  right: 0;
}


.main-advantages__title {
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    font-size: 25px;

}
.main-advantages__text {
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="container">
  <section class="main-advantages">
    <div class="main-advantages__goods"> 
      <img class="main-advantages__img" src="img/rose.png" alt="Rose">
    </div>
    <div class="main-advantages__inner">
      <div class="main-advantages__number">
        <span>01</span>
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-advantages__title"> Эксклюзивная подача </h2>
      <p class="main-advantages__text"> Роскошный подарок в дизайнерской коробке, подписанная именем получателя – подарок, достойный королевы.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-advantages__inner">
      <div class="main-advantages__number">
        <span>02</span>
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-advantages__title"> Неповторимые эмоции </h2>
      <p class="main-advantages__text"> Неожиданно удивите и обрадуйте дорого вам человека, подарив ему внимание и коробку прекрасных, свежих роз.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-advantages__inner">
      <div class="main-advantages__number">
        <span>03</span>
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-advantages__title"> Осязаемая роскошь </h2>
      <p class="main-advantages__text"> Мы находимся вне конкуренции обычных букетов. Наша подача всегда будет выделяться на фоне остальных подарков.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-advantages__inner">
      <div class="main-advantages__number">
        <span>04</span>
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-advantages__title"> Длительная неувядаемость </h2>
      <p class="main-advantages__text"> Наши розы живы дольше, чем в шляпных коробках, поскольку каждый цветок мы укладываем в отдельную капсулу с водой</p>
    </div>
  </section>
      </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: от меня плюсик (+)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let span = document.querySelectorAll('span');
let advantages__number = document.querySelectorAll('.main-advantages__number');

let span1;

for( let i = 0; i < span.length; i++ ){
  span1 = span[i].innerHTML.slice(1);
  if( span1 % 2 == 0 ){
    advantages__number[i].style.right = 0 + 'px';
  } else{
   advantages__number[i].style.left = 0 + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container{
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-advantages {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.main-advantages__goods {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-advantages__img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -18%);
    max-height: 984px;
    object-position: center center;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.main-advantages__inner {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 520px;
    &:nth-child(odd){
        text-align: right;
        padding: 130px 165px 0px 0;
    }
    &:nth-child(even){
        text-align: left;
        padding: 130px 0 0px 165px;
    }
}

.main-advantages__number {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 95px;
    height: 95px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    line-height: 1;
    span{
        transform: translate(0, -5px);
    }
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="container">
  <section class="main-advantages">
    <div class="main-advantages__goods"> 
      <!-- <img class="main-advantages__img" src="img/rose.png" alt="Rose"> -->
    </div>
    <div class="main-advantages__inner">
      <div class="main-advantages__number">
        <span>01</span>
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-advantages__title"> Эксклюзивная подача </h2>
      <p class="main-advantages__text"> Роскошный подарок в дизайнерской коробке, подписанная именем получателя – подарок, достойный королевы.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-advantages__inner">
      <div class="main-advantages__number">
        <span>02</span>
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-advantages__title"> Неповторимые эмоции </h2>
      <p class="main-advantages__text"> Неожиданно удивите и обрадуйте дорого вам человека, подарив ему внимание и коробку прекрасных, свежих роз.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-advantages__inner">
      <div class="main-advantages__number">
        <span>03</span>
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-advantages__title"> Осязаемая роскошь </h2>
      <p class="main-advantages__text"> Мы находимся вне конкуренции обычных букетов. Наша подача всегда будет выделяться на фоне остальных подарков.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-advantages__inner">
      <div class="main-advantages__number">
        <span>04</span>
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-advantages__title"> Длительная неувядаемость </h2>
      <p class="main-advantages__text"> Наши розы живы дольше, чем в шляпных коробках, поскольку каждый цветок мы укладываем в отдельную капсулу с водой</p>
    </div>
  </section>
      </div>
    </main>
```